# Options for displaying/running a HTML file with JS code rather than having to execute it every time in the terminal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, terminal, runtime

I have a very simple project, and index.html, style.css, and a script.js. My script.js file contains an input filed where one can enter a quote which is then displayed and styled on my index.html file.

My question is, what possibilities are out there for displaying this file rather than having to run it through my terminal every time I want to see it? I would love to have this display as a widget in the corner of my computer screen so that I can always see it and update it. Or perhaps there is a way to upload the code to a device with a screen and have it run 24/7 on there?

Comment: What do you mean by "My script.js file contains an input filed"? This script is runned on NodeJs or on browser or other platform?

Comment: Nodejs... its an external file that I pulled it into my html so that every time I load my html the js also runs and updates